# How do I stop my array from being overwritten in every iteration?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code in vb.net:

```
Do Until StreamReader.Peek() = -1 _
            OrElse intSubscript >= EmployeeData.Length
    Line = StreamReader.ReadLine()

    EmployeeData = Line.Split(" ")

    intSubscript += 1
Loop
```

I am trying to read a sequential filled such as this one:

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20

I want to my loop to read one line per iteration and for every line read, I want it to be split by spaces and then stored in an array (EmployeeData(50)).

My issue as stated above is that my array gets reset and replaced by the values of the next iteration instead of being added to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is on line.

```
EmployeeData = Line.Split(" ")
```

As of me you need to append next row value to this list. if EmployeeData is list type then you can use `AddRange` to add current iterate value like below:

```
EmployeeData.AddRange(Line.Split(" "))
```